# iMac HDD fan running full speed. What is wrong?

Tags: hard-drive, imac, temperature

My iMac (27" Mid-2010) and the HDD fan is spinning full speed with a measured HDD temperature of 50 °C. I have removed the dust and dirt from inside and it is pretty clean. Nevertheless even when at idle it starts at 48 °C.

I've tried to use software to control the fans in order to decrease temp but the lowest it gets is 47 °C. I checked every single connection inside and everything seems to be ok. I also tried resetting the SMC and PRAM but with no luck.

#### Specs

- 27" Mid-2010
- 2.93GHz
- Stock HDD 1.5TB Seagate st1500dl003
- OS X Mavericks 10.9.4 and Windows 8.1 under Boot Camp

Comment: Anything taking up unusual amounts of CPU in Activity Monitor?

Comment: I don't think so because it has the same behaviour when on windows 8.1 (under bootcamp)

Comment: What's the ambient temperature in the room? What is the CPU loading? (`iostat` on the command line is a nice way to get definite numbers.)

Comment: approximately 24 degrees ambient temp in the room. I will have to check the cpu loading and i will report back. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the drive experiences overheating issue. Unfortunately it's a common issue for Seagate drives which happens with time (had exactly the same problem with iMac 2010 21.5`` and stock 500 GB hdd). I used free [Macs Fan Control](http://www.crystalidea.com/solving-imac-fan-noise-issue-after-hdd-replacement) tool to cool down the HDD (specially in Boot Camp, where the drive was even hotter). The article is about HDD replacement but it also explains how to use the app.

But the best solution I think is to replace the drive with some 2.5`` drive. They are known to be much cooler and quiter (though slower)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried an SMC reset? The SMC controls fan speed and operation. Give it a shot.

SMC reset (how to perform) and symptoms needing one described in this kbase:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964

Comment: Hi. Yes i have tried SMC multiple times with no luck.

Comment: My apologies, I did not fully read the question!

Comment: Consider deleting this as it doesn't actually solve the problem